# MySQL - insert into... on duplicate key update - How to distinguish between insert or update?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am using Node.js. I use `mysql` and `bluebird` packages.

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({ ... });

const query = (stmt, params) => {
    return Promise.promisify(pool.query, { context: pool })(stmt, params);
};

const params = { ... };

const stmt = 'insert into table set ? on duplicate key update ?';

return query(stmt, [params, params])
    .then(results => {
        // I want to know actually what is done, insert or update
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a key `affectedRows` from the return object. From the reference, `affectedRows` will be 1 if it is inserted, and 0 or 2 if it is updated.

```
return query(stmt, [params, params])
    .then(results => {
        // I want to know actually what is done, insert or update
        if (results.affectedRows === 1) {
            // inserted
        } else {
            // updated
        }
    });
```

> For INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag, the affected-rows value is 1 (not 0) if an existing row is set to its current values.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html

Comment: Thanks so much! `FOUND_ROWS` is defaulted to on. I turn it off and your answer is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not as savvy with this bit of node api, the basics are the same:

```
query(stmt, [params.col1, params.col2])
.then(results => {
    Console.log("Affected rows: " + results.affectedRows);
});
```

Now, the real problem is that MySQL is a fan of essentially returning garbage diagnostic information. If you modify more than 1 row, you'll have no idea what occurred on each one, [thanks to this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value **per row** is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values.

If you can afford it, do these statements one at a time, and check the affected row count. Otherwise, I'm digging through some MySQL internal functions but I'm not seeing much.

As a side note,  you're overreaching with your wildcards there. Instead, use that space to update/insert the columns you want, and parameterize the input values:

```
-- Please don't name it 'table'
INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2)
    VALUES (?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column1 = VALUES(column1), column2 = VALUES(column2)
```